# Are javax.servlet-api and commons-dbcp important in our Spring Apps?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

How to understand the importance of javax.servlet-api and commons-dbcp in our Spring application.

When we must use it and where is the implementation should we do?

Because i have build.gradle something like this

```
dependencies {
    //compile('javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0')
    //compile('commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4')

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')

    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.31')

    compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4')

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

If i remove the javax.servlet-api and commons-dbcp from my build.gradle, my application can still run as expected.

And so what are they (javax.servlet-api and commons-dbcp) actually do in the behind of scene?

Maybe i know why, because it's has been covered out-of-the-box by Spring Boot Starter. But, where is the explanation about it, i can't found it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need those dependencies. javax.servlet-api is provided by [tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/package-summary.html). commons-dbcp is a connection pool, but tomcat already includes it's own [connection pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) as a transitive dependency.
`gradle dependencyInsight --dependency tomcat-jdbc` output:

```
org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:8.0.30 (selected by rule)
\--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:1.3.1.RELEASE
     \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.3.1.RELEASE
```

You should use the tomcat connection pool.

> We prefer the Tomcat pooling DataSource for its performance and
>   concurrency, so if that is available we always choose it.

[Spring-Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database)

Comment: Thanks, now i understand a little bit. So, if i've spring-boot-starter-data-jpa in my **build.gradle**, that's enough, right?

Comment: yw, you also need the starter- thymeleaf you want to use thymeleaf templates and the mysql jdbc driver as it is not included in the starter-data-jpa.

Comment: haha, i mean spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf also. Okay, thanks for your help.